# What is wrong with angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view that displays a list of items. To get those items I use a service with the following public interface

```
     return {                
                items: _items,
                getItems: _getItems,
                getItemById: _getItemById,
                item: _item
            };
```

The service local variables are:

```
var _items = [];
var _item;
```

items array is filled when I call getItems().
However, when someone selects an item from the list. I use the getItemById(id) to fetch and init _item variable. (The item is found and appears to init the `_item`.

But there is something wrong cause when I try to access the item from my controller it appears as undefined. `itemsService.item`

```
            var _getItemById = function (id) {
                _item = null;

                $.each(_items, function (i, item) {
                    if (item.id == id) {
                        _item = item;
                        console.log(_item); //this works
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
```

I want to keep track of the selected item, as I have pages like "ItemsList", "ItemDetail", "ItemExtra" etc. This is why i decided to keep track of the item in my service. maybe there is a better practise ?

Comment: change your service to `return {items : return _items,getItems:...}`

Comment: seems to work :) However I dont get it, cause items which is array is directly accessible.

Comment: what does `getItemById(id)` do?

Comment: typo mistake.. It is the same as getGirlById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

change your service to return {items : return _items,getItems:...}